# Can We Replace Effect of Pen and Paper using Tablets or Typing?

Tags: psychology, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does handwriting assist memory retention more effectively than typing?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/does-handwriting-assist-memory-retention-more-effectively-than-typing)

Often I read about the tips to remember better is by writing them down. I don't have this habit as I can't take note while listening. So, I always focus more on understanding what the speakers are talking.

When I started working, I find out that I can't think without pen and paper. When I need to think about a solution or and idea, I need to plan them on a paper not a machine.

So, I'm wondering if there is any research done to test if using computers to take notes have the same effect with taking notes on paper and pen.

Comment: All my notes for school are on my iPad, but they are all hand written. I can't retain information by typing it. I need to have it written down.